# Batch command open folders according to preference

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

```
@echo off
start /wait /min C:\Folder1
start /wait /min C:\Folder2
start /wait /min C:\Folder3
start /wait /min C:\Folder4
```

I wanted to use Batch file to get windows to open up folders and arrange them like Folder1 Folder2 Folder3 Folder4 and so on...

Instead I am getting random arrangement... e.g. Folder2 Folder3 Folder1 Folder4

Anyway to arrange them to open according to my preference?

Thanks.

P.S. I am using Windows 8 64 bit FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get them to appear in the order you call them by invoking `explorer` with the specified path

```
explorer C:\Folder1
explorer C:\Folder2
explorer C:\Folder3
explorer C:\Folder4
```

Comment: However explorer doesn't seem to allow use of /min or does it allow minimize?

Comment: start /min explorer C:\Folder1 still gives random folder loading however I found adding start /wait /min explorer C:\Folder1 helps. Thanks Bali C  my question is answered